# strange thing with clojure split

Tags: regex

```
(clojure.string/split "hello world" #" ")
```

["hello" "world"]

Whereas,

```
(clojure.string/split "hello|world" #"|")
```

output:
["h"
 "e"
 "l"
 "l"
 "o"
 "|"
 "w"
 "o"
 "r"
 "l"
 "d"]

Why the string does not split on "|"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`|` has special meaning in regular expressions, so you must *escape* it (by prefixing it with `\`) if you want to split on that literal character:

```
(clojure.string/split "hello|world" #"\|")
=> ["hello" "world"]
```