# (split "cat|of|dog" #"|") does not work as intended in Clojure

Tags: regex

Output received by doing `(split "cat|of|dog" #"|")`:

```
["c"
 "a"
 "t"
 "|"
 "o"
 "f"
 "|"
 "d"
 "o"
 "g"]
```

But the intended output is "cat", "of", "dog".
If I do the split using any other character like "," - it works just fine.

Comment: "|" is the or operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strange thing with clojure split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50653610/strange-thing-with-clojure-split)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to split is a regex, not a string. To split on `|` you should therefore write `#"\|"` or `#"[|]"`. Similarly, to split on one of a collection of characters you should write `#"a|b|c"` or `#"[abc]"`.

Comment: Using "\|" does work. But can you explain why "(str/split "cat,dog" #"\,")" and "(str/split "cat,dog" #",")"  work the same.

Comment: because they both define zero length delimiter

Comment: The regex "," just matches the string ",", but the character "|" has a special meaning: it's used to link two regexes. So "|" matches either "" (on the left) or "" (on the write). Using a backslash tells it that you're referring to the character |.